# How to find the parameter name expected in laravel model route binding

Tags: laravel, route-model-binding

I have a route like this

`Route::get('/vcs-integrations/{vcs-provider}/authenticate','VcsIntegrationsController@authenticate');`

and the method to handle the route I am using the model route binding to happen is as follows

```
<?php

....
use App\Models\VcsProvider;
....

class VcsIntegrationsController extends Controller
{
  public function authenticate(VcsProvider $vcsProvider, Request $request)
    {
        ...
        // some logic
        ...
    }
}
```

when I try to access the route I am getting 404 due to the parameter name is not matching.

**So, how do I know the parameter name expected by laravel in route model binding ?**

Comment: have you tried: php artisan route:list , it will show you the routes with their parameters names, use ctrl + f to find your route ..

Comment: it shows `{vcs-provider}`  and in PHP you can't create `$vcs-provider` variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the route parameter docs:

> "Route parameters are always encased within `{}` braces and should consist of alphabetic characters,  and may not contain a `-` character. Instead of using the `-` character, use an underscore `(_)`." - [Laravel 7.x Docs - Routing - Route Parameters - Required Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#required-parameters)

You should be able to define the parameter as `{vcs_provider}` in the route definition and then use `$vcs_provider` for the parameter name in the method signature if you would like. You can also name it not using the `_` if you prefer, but just avoid the `-`, hyphen, when naming.

Have fun and good luck.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions **whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name**.

This means that if you want implicit binding to work, you need to name the route param same as your variable. Since your variable's name is **vcsProvider**, your route should be:

Route::get('/vcs-integrations/{**vcsProvider**}/authenticate','VcsIntegrationsController@authenticate');

Comment: This is also a right answer. But since I didn't want the parameter names to be camel cased I find @lagbox's answer more appropriate. Thank you :)